# CSRF token fails on form submission when CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN is set

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-csrf

I am setting `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN='.localhost'`. After setting this form submission fails with csrf token error. Here are the details:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3fde73be4d3541223cf93b8e703169c1

If I don't set `csrf_cookie_domain` csrf fails in ajax request. I am passing csrf token on each ajax requests.

Comment: So you're setting it to `.example` but developing on `localhost:8000`?

Comment: No I have set both to localhost:8000.

Comment: Still the same?

Comment: Yeah! If I remove CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN the form post works but ajax one fails.

Comment: Do you put `localhost` in quotes? like CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "localhost:8000"?

Comment: If so, try setting it to "127.0.0.1" instead.

Comment: Yeah, I do. I set it to "127.0.0.1" instead, still the same error.

Comment: Dumb question :) do you have cookies enabled or maybe you're using internet explorer?

Comment: Oh no. I see you're using mac.

Comment: hehe no man, I am using Chrome and testing in Firefox sometimes.

Comment: And cookies are enabled.

Comment: I'm out of ideas really.

Comment: This is bugging me for 2 days.